# How to implement 'Snap to center' feature for lists in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, epoxy, android-jetpack-compose-list

In EpoxyRecyclerView with Horizontal LinearLayout there is a Snap to center feature which works like, If i scroll the list with good speed, it keeps on scrolling until it slows down and rests with an item at center. And if I scroll slowly and lift up the finger, then the next item spans/moves to center of screen. One thing you have to understand that, this is not a Pager. Pager automatically snaps the next item only. But I cannot scroll like a free rolling...

You can see this gif as an example

[image]

So, I'm looking for such snapping feature in Jetpack Compose. Is this possible yet? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: [HorizontalViewPager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager).

Comment: @Jay the the library you gave is a normal viewpager which is clearly mentioned that is not what I'm looking for... I also need the list to scroll freely several items

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Compose 1.3 you can check the `SnapFlingBehavior` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/snapping/SnapFlingBehavior)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this library as well https://github.com/chrisbanes/snapper

https://chrisbanes.github.io/snapper/

val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

```
LazyRow(
    state = lazyListState,
    flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(lazyListState),
) {
    // content
}
```

Comment: This does not work with scrolling on Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with compose [`1.3.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0) you can use the [`FlingBehavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/snapping/SnapFlingBehavior) that performs snapping of items to a given position:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()

LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    state = state,
    flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = state)
) {
  //item content
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try out this library: https://github.com/aakarshrestha/compose-pager-snap-helper
The code will look as follows (using `LazyRow` for listing the items)

```
ComposePagerSnapHelper(
        width = 320.dp, //required
        content = { listState -> //this param is provided by the method itself, add this param below.
            LazyRow(
                state = listState, //add listState param
            ) {
                items(count = count) { item ->
                    //Put your Items Composable here
                }
            }
        }
    )
```