# How can I implement snap to center in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I have a DateTime picker and I want to get the center item value list by scrolling. I think it's called "Snap To Center" how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Which component or library do you use? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What do you mean by "Snap To Center"? Instead of picking up the name of the effect you want to see, describe how it should work.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I mean is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571319/how-to-implement-snap-to-center-feature-for-lists-in-jetpack-compose.     but this library is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](https://github.com/ChargeMap/Compose-NumberPicker)

but I cloned the related class and used it